# Assembly basic calculator runtime problems

Tags: assembly, mips32

Ok so i want to create a simple program to calculate numeric expressions.User gives an integer-an operator **(+, -, *, / ,%)**-then an integer and so on, until he enters "=" in which case we print the result.Then we ask if user wants to calculate another expression and depending on answer we either go back to start or exit the program.Program automatically exits when operation input is not supported or 0 is given as input when operators **/ or %** are selected(no check for the numbers is required).Here is my code :

```
.data

str0: .asciiz "nWelcome to Interactive Calculator 1.0"
str1: .asciiz " Enter operand: "
str2: .asciiz " Enter (+, -,*, /,&) or '=' to print result: "
str3: .asciiz " Enter second value: "
str4: .asciiz " Invalid Operator! Try again. "
str5: .asciiz " Result is: "
str6: .asciiz " Another Calculation? y, n: "
str7: .asciiz " Invalid input! Please enter y or n."
str8: .asciiz " Calculator Terminated or error in input(operation error or 0 as input in div or rem."
CRLF: .asciiz "\n"


.text
.globl main

main:
la $a0, str0
li $v0, 4
syscall #printing str0

la $a0, CRLF
li $v0, 4
syscall

calc:

la $a0, str1
li $v0, 4
syscall #printing str1


li $v0,5
syscall #read operand and store it
add $s0 ,$v0, $zero

la $a0, CRLF
li $v0, 4
syscall #change line

la $a0, str2
li $v0, 4
syscall #printing str2



getoperation:
li $v0,12
syscall # reading operation and saving it
la $s1,($v0)


la $a0, CRLF
li $v0, 4
syscall #change line

beq $s1,'=', printres #check if operation is =

beq $s1,'+', addnum #check if operation is +

beq $s1,'-', subnum #check if operation is -

beq $s1,'*', mulnum #check if operation is *

beq $s1,'/', divnum #check if operation is /

beq $s1,'%', remnum #check if operation is %

addnum:
la $a0, str1
li $v0, 4
syscall #printing str1
li $v0,5
syscall #read operand and perform add
add $s0 ,$s0, $v0
j getoperation

subnum:
la $a0, str1
li $v0, 4
syscall #printing str1
li $v0,5
syscall #read operand and perform sub
sub $s0 ,$s0, $v0
j getoperation

mulnum:
la $a0, str1
li $v0, 4
syscall #printing str1
li $v0,5
syscall #read operand and perform mul
mul $s0 ,$s0, $v0
j getoperation

divnum:
la $a0, str1
li $v0, 4
syscall #printing str1
li $v0,5
syscall #read operand and check its not 0
bgez $v0,exitApp
div $s0,$s0,$v0
j getoperation

remnum:
la $a0, str1
li $v0, 4
syscall #printing str1
li $v0,5
syscall #read operand and check its not 0
bgez $v0,exitApp
rem $s0,$s0,$v0
j getoperation

printres:
la $a0, str5
li $v0, 4
syscall #printing str5
move $a0,$s0
li $v0,1
syscall
j anothercalc

j exitApp

anothercalc:
la $a0, str0
li $v0, 4
syscall #printing str6
li $v0,12
syscall #reading input y/n
add $a1, $v0, $0    #storing command

addi $9, $0, 0x79
beq $a1, $9, calc   #checking if y

addi $9, $0, 0x6e
beq $a1, $9, exitApp    #checking if n

la $a0, str0
li $v0, 4 
syscall #printing str7
j anothercalc



exitApp:
la $a0, str8
li $v0, 4
syscall #printing str0


li $v0,10
syscall
```

But when i try to run through QTspim i fall into infinite loop after i enter the 1st operator...Picture with result available:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOXuU.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stored the *address* of the string that the user entered for the operator, but are comparing that to the *character codes* of your operators.  Thus, none of the tests succeed, and you code "falls through" into `addnum`, which asks for a operand, then goes back to asking for an operator.  Thus, it never detects entering `=` to end the loop.

Comment: Ok but how do i fix this?

Comment: Compare your operator with the character *at* the address in `$s1`, instead of the address itself.

Comment: So instead of **beq $s1,'=', printres #check if operation is =** what should i write???Thanks and sorry in advance

Comment: There is an instruction, `lb` ("load byte") to move a byte from a specified address into a register.

Comment: So i did this: lb $s2,($s1) and then tried to compare like before: **beg $s2,'='** but when i give as input any operator i get the error:

**Bad address in data/stack read: 0x0000002b **